# Login page and Servlet process flow

Tags: servlets, authentication, jdeveloper

I am trying to understand a process involved in logging in a user. I was told a servlet needed to be made in order to access the headers of a request/response.

So one was made, it grabs the header info, then checks to make sure the user is a valid user in the database. If so, it sets the session with this user. If not, it directs to the registration page.

My issues is in understanding what calls this servlet, is a "start page needed to call this servlet?"

Answer (score 1):

> *... access the headers of a request/response ... graps the header info ...*

You're describing the way how `BASIC` HTTP authentication works. This is the well-known JavaScript alert look-a-like popup which asks for the username and password and results in a HTTP 401 Not Authorized error when incorrect credentials are provided. This is in a Java EE web application normally not performed by a servlet at all, but by a specific `web.xml` configuration setting. It look like this:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>secured</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/secured/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>someRoleName</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

The location of the users and roles are configured in the servletcontainer itself. This can be a XML file, or a database. You need to refer the servletcontainer specific documentation using the keyword "realm" how to configure it. For Tomcat for example it's the [Tomcat Realm HOWTO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html).

Another way is `FORM` based authentication, but this does not involve passing the login information by request headers as you initially asked. Also, usually no servlets are involved at all since this is automatically performed by container's builtin mechanisms. You only need to change the `<login-config>` from above to below:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

The `login.jsp` should in turn have a HTML form which should submit by POST to a predefinied URL `j_security_check` with the username and password as predefinied request parameters `j_username` and `j_password`.

```
<form action="j_security_check" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="j_username" />
    <input type="password" name="j_password" />
    <input type="submit" value="login" />
</form>
```

This has the advantage that you can present the page with the login form with some nice HTML/CSS/JS the way you want instead of showing a bare JavaScript look-a-like dialog.

A servlet is only been used when a programmatic login is to be performed by calling [`request.login(username, password)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#login%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). This method is new since Servlet 3.0 (Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, etc). Note that this still requires a `<security-constraint>` in `web.xml` and a realm in the container. Servlets are also also only been used when you're homegrowing authentication using a [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) instead of using container managed authentication. In the servlet, you should then store your own database model representation of the logged-in user in the session like so [`session.setAttribute("user", user)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) so that the filter can intercept on that.

#### See also:

- [Java EE 6 tutorial - securing web applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncas.html)

Note that JDeveloper is **unrelated** to this all. It's just a tool (an IDE) to easily develop Java web applications. You can as good do the same in Eclipse, Netbeans, IntelliJ or even notepad.

Comment: Hello BaluscC, Thanks for the reply. I am using JDeveloper 11.1.2.x.x. I am also trying to do a completely programatic login, the user will be validated by F5 Big-Ip, so the login process is really just a valdation of the users in the DB.

Comment: Hello BaluscC, Thanks for the reply. I am using JDeveloper 11.1.2.x.x. I am also trying to do a completely programatic login, the user will be validated by F5 Big-Ip, so the login process is really just a valdation of the users in the DB.  If not then the user shoud register in the system.  So is this completely just a configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on what kind of security you want to implement. You mention that the identity store is RDBMS (table I assume) which allows you to implement two types of authentication: container managed and custom. In a custom authentication (less recommended) you challenge the user for his/her username/password pair and compare it to users in your database. There is no automated authentication checking in this and a servlet filter would be needed to ensure users are authenticated when they access a protected resource.

Container managed - indicated by the previous answer - allows you to delegate the authentication to the container. In this case the application you write (and you may get more specific on this) is doesn't handle authentication and authentication tracking itself but just - through configuration in web.xml - redirects the request to the container for authentication.

Most application servers allow you to configure the identity store to authenticate users against. With WebLogic server, the default in JDeveloper, this could be LDAP, Active Directory, OID, integrated LDAP in WLS and SQL/Table. The latter is a pre-defined authentication provider (SQL authentication provider) that allows you to configure the WLS container to authenticate your users against database tables.

So I recommend you follow up with container managed authentication using the SQL Authentication provider as it means less work